# React memory game: state update out of sync

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a 4x4 memory game. How I have things set up currently is that when a square is clicked, the color and index of the square is sent to "holder" in state.

Once there are 2 objects in "holder", I check to see if they are matching colors, if so they remain status.clicked = "true", otherwise, the indexes in the holder are mapped over status and reset to status.clicked = "false".

After there have been 2 objects in "holder", I reset holder to an empty array. However, it seems the next click doesn't register in the "holder" and it gets skipped entirely, which causes all the functionality to misalign.

Do you know why this isn't working? Feedback greatly appreciated.

sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-bas-v3d80?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Box({thing, index, style, updateStatus}){
  return(
    <button type="button" className="Box" style={style(index)} onClick={() => updateStatus(index)}>
      <div>
        {thing[index].status}
      </div>
    </button>
  )
}

function App() {
    const [status, setStatus] = useState([
      {status: null, clicked: false, color: 'red'},
      {status: null, clicked: false, color: 'red'},
      {status: null, clicked: false, color: 'yellow'},
      {status: null, clicked: false, color: 'yellow'},
      {status: null, clicked: false, color: 'blue'},
      {status: null, clicked: false, color: 'blue'},
      {status: null, clicked: false, color: 'orange'},
      {status: null, clicked: false, color: 'orange'},
      {status: null, clicked: false, color: 'pink'},
      {status: null, clicked: false, color: 'pink'},
      {status: null, clicked: false, color: 'purple'},
      {status: null, clicked: false, color: 'purple'},
      {status: null, clicked: false, color: 'white'},
      {status: null, clicked: false, color: 'white'},
      {status: null, clicked: false, color: 'green'},
      {status: null, clicked: false, color: 'green'}
    ]);

    const [holder, setHolder] = useState([

    ])

      function updateStatus(index){
        const newStatus = [...status]
        newStatus[index].clicked = true
        const newHolder = [...holder, {"index": newStatus.indexOf(newStatus[index]), "color": newStatus[index].color}]
        setHolder(newHolder)
        if (holder.length === 2 && !holderTest(holder)){
          const newHolder2 = [...status]
          holder.map(holder => {newHolder2[holder.index].clicked = false})
          setStatus(newHolder2)
          setHolder([])
        }
        if (holder.length === 2){setHolder([])}
    }

console.log(holder.length)
console.log(holder)
console.log(status)

    function holderTest(holderToTest){
      if (holderToTest[0].color === holderToTest[1].color){return true}
    }

      function colorChange(index){
        return (
          {backgroundColor: status[index].clicked ? status[index].color : 'black'})
    }

    return (
          <div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="column">
                <Box thing={status} index={0} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={1} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={2} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={3} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
              </div>
              <div className="column">
                <Box thing={status} index={4} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={5} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={6} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={7} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
              </div>
              <div className="column">
                <Box thing={status} index={8} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={9} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={10} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={11} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
              </div>
              <div className="column">
                <Box thing={status} index={12} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={13} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={14} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={15} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be better off rethinking this a little

https://codesandbox.io/s/red-fire-pg16s

A better system would be:

- To have the data for which you want to display boxes
- To remember which box is currently held
- To remember which boxes have already been matched (I use a Set for efficient membership checks)

Then when you are rendering in React you have a purely state driven approach. I.e.

- Is this box already matched => should not be clickable and should appear in its real colour
- Is this box currently held => Should not be clickable and should appear in its real colour. Also, put a border on it.
- Otherwise, display the box with no colour (grey in this case)

Also, now Box doesn't need any knowledge of data structures, it's always told explicitly what to do.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function Box({ color, index, held, matched, selectHandler }) {
  const displayColor = held || matched ? color : "grey";
  const onClick = held || matched ? null : () => selectHandler(index);
  const style = { backgroundColor: displayColor };
  if (held) {
    style["border"] = "4px solid black";
  }
  return (
    <button type="button" className="Box" style={style} onClick={onClick}>
      <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    </button>
  );
}

const data = [
  "red",
  "red",
  "yellow",
  "yellow",
  "blue",
  "blue",
  "orange",
  "orange",
  "pink",
  "pink",
  "purple",
  "purple",
  "white",
  "white",
  "green",
  "green"
];

function App() {
  // A record of a box currently being matched
  const [heldIndex, setHeldIndex] = useState(null);
  // A record of previously matched boxes
  const [matched, setMatched] = useState(new Set());

  function updateStatus(index) {
    // If nothing has been "held" already, "hold" this box
    if (heldIndex === null) {
      setHeldIndex(index);
      // Otherwise, see if it's a match with the held box
    } else {
      // If it's a match, set both of those as matched
      if (data[index] === data[heldIndex]) {
        setMatched(new Set([...Array.from(matched), index, heldIndex]));
      }
      // Match or no match, nothing should be held after an attempted pairing
      setHeldIndex(null);
    }
  }

  // I didn't bother laying them out in a grid, I leave that to you
  // Previously matched boxes are "matched === true"
  // Currently held box is "held === true"
  const boxes = data.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <Box
        key={index}
        color={item}
        index={index}
        held={index === heldIndex}
        matched={matched.has(index)}
        selectHandler={updateStatus}
      />
    );
  });

  return <div>{boxes}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, very, very helpful. I realize now I took a less than ideal approach to this challenge. 
I'm curious, is my current code at all salvageable? I believe the issue lies on line 56 and 59. Looking at the console.log, by the third click, my matching array is reset without the third click data in place.

Comment: One problem is the expectation that `holder` will be updated immediately when calling `setHolder` as it looks like you update the holder with the second clicked item, and then check how many items are in holder. Thks wont work because your function " “sees” the props and state from the render it was created". https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function

Comment: I do think you could salvage this, but I think it would help the logic to switch to using a single value as holder. There is no need to ever store more than one because on a click you can easily compare this new clicked item with the previously "held" item.

Comment: Thank you for this, making more sense to me now. Very grateful for your help.